# ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, import, python-3.x, migrate, visa

I'm migrating PyVisa from Python 2.6 to Python 3.2. I'm able to install the module.
It's listed in `C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa`

The `__init__.py` file imports a module (`vpp43.py`) from this folder. At this line I get following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Documents and Settings\grknbl16\My Documents\PatternControl.py", line 2, in <module>
> from taborAwg import configTabor
> File "D:\Documents and Settings\grknbl16\My Documents\taborAwg.py", line 1, in <module>
> from visa import Instrument, vpp43
> File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\visa.py", line 1, in <module>
> from pyvisa.visa import *
> File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
> import configparser, os, sys, vpp43
> ImportError: No module named vpp43
> ```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3.x implicit relative imports have gone away.  Instead of

```
import configparser, os, sys, vpp43
```

`pyvisa\__init__.py` needs to say:

```
import configparser, os, sys
from . import vpp43
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the above answer got selected, although I can't see how it possibly can be correct.

Comment: I'm going to agree with the above.  Per the example found at http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/pyporting.html#supporting-python-2-5-and-newer-only, using the above would allow you to perform this sort of import.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found the tool 2to3.py which also shows me this solution.