# How to use Pyvisa1.4 in Python3.2, a lot of unexpected errors generated

Tags: python, ctypes, visa

Previously I've used `PyVisa1.4` in `Python2.7`, and everything works fine.
Now I need to use `Pyvisa1.4` in `Python3.2`.

I knew that some syntax are changed in Python3.2. Therefore I use the `2to3` to convert the originalPysiva `.py` files into the new format which are supposed to fit the Python3.2.

But now, unexpected error is generated which is related to `ctypes`. And I read through the Pyvisa package `.py` files and try to fix this but still don't know how to do deal with this.

I'm just trying to use the simple `get_instruments_list()` command like below:

```
>>> import visa
>>> get_instruments_list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    get_instruments_list()
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\visa.py", line 254, in get_instruments_list
    vpp43.find_resources(resource_manager.session, "?*::INSTR")
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\vpp43.py", line 581, in find_resources
instrument_description)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

The MAIN problem I'm facing now is how to correctly use `PyVisa` in `Python3.2`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605036/importerror-no-module-named

Comment: @Alex. My question is totally different from that one. The reason why he got that error is because he use the `Python2.` syntax. But I've used the `2to3` to convert the format of `pyvisa`.

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps you might be able to try without 2to3, similarly to what he's done

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The newest version of `Pyvisa` doesn't support `Python3.2`

Even thouhg you convert the syntax of `Pyvisa1.4` for `Python2.X` to `Python3.X` by using `2to3` tool, it still won't work

Comment: This is actually not completely true. While it is not supported you can use the 2to3 script to convert most of the changes and the errors that pop up are fixable. A lot of times it is a simple ascii conversion (That error is fixed by puting a `bytes(string, 'ascii')` where "string" is the second argument in the call. That particular error comes up a lot, but it is always the same fix.

Answer (score 2):

PyVISA 1.5 (which is in beta now) provides, among other things, full Python 3 support. Take a look at the (new) documentation for instructions about how to download the latest development version at http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the str that is passed as second argument.
In Python 3 the str was radically changed in order to support unicode.
To correct this problem all strings before being passed to the DLL library must be encoded in ASCII.
Conversely, the return strings are returned as bytes should be converted back into str.

I have corrected this on the visa.py, on the

```
CR = "\r" replaces CR = b"\r"
LF = "\n" replaces LF = b"\n"
```

ResourceTemplate **init**

```
self.vi = vpp43.open(resource_manager.session, resource_name.encode("ASCII"),
                             keyw.get("lock", VI_NO_LOCK))
```

instead of

```
self.vi = vpp43.open(resource_manager.session, resource_name,
                             keyw.get("lock", VI_NO_LOCK))
```

Instrument.write

```
vpp43.write(self.vi, message.encode("ASCII"))
```

instead of

```
vpp43.write(self.vi, message)
```

conversely on the read_raw the final return is replaced by

```
return str(buffer)
```

and on get_instruments_list()

```
vpp43.find_resources(resource_manager.session, "?*::INSTR".encode("ASCII"))
```